# ocaml extremely large data structure suggestions

Tags: list, data-structures, ocaml, large-data

I am looking for suggestions on what kind of data-structure to use for extremely large structures in OCaml that scale well.

By scales well, I don't want stack overflows, or exponential heap growth, assuming there is enough memory.  So this pretty much eliminates the standard lib's List.map function.  Speed isn't so much an issue.

But for starters, let's assume I'm operating in the realm of 2^10 - 2^100 items.

There are only three "manipulations" I perform on the structure:

(1) a map function on subsets of the structure, which either increases or decreases the structure

(2) scanning the structure

(3) removal of specific pairs of items in the structure that satisfy a particular criterion

Originally I was using regular lists, which is still highly desirable, because the structure is constantly changing.  Usually after all manipulations are performed, the structure has at most either doubled in size (or something thereabouts), or reduced to the empty list [].  Perhaps the doubling dooms me from the beginning but it is unavoidable.

In any event, around 2^15 --- 2^40 items start causing severe problems (probably due to the naive list functions I was using as well).  The program uses 100% of the cpu, but almost no memory, and generally after a day or two it stack-overflows.

I would prefer to start using more memory, if possible, in order to continue operating in larger spaces.

Anyway, if anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "enough memory". 2 ^ 100 is 10^30.  If each "item" is just 1 bit, you're still talking 125 quadrillion terabytes.

Comment: Ya, at that point, and much before, would probably have to do lazy lists or sequences a la batteries, obviously couldn't store the whole structure in memory.  But I'm not sure what to use, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Very large indeed: 2^100 is 10^30 and 2^10000 is 10^3000. For comparison purposes, there are about 10^24 stars in the universe, and 10^80 atoms. Are you sure about those numbers?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your observations and comments.  I realized they were too large when I got home --- the numbers are coming from degenerate binary trees at maximum those sizes.  I've removed the ridiculously large numbers, so now we can proceed to the example of 2^15 and onwards, so we can hopefully get constructive comments on what OCaml _data_ _structure_ to use for structures that are large, but less than the number of stars in the visible universe ;)  Although unfortunately I've been doing some calculations and I think the structures expand after the manipulation from 2^p -> 2^(2*p-2)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough space, in theory, to contain all items of your data structure, you should look at data structures that have an efficient memory representation, with as few bookeeping as possible. Dynamic arrays (that you resize exponentially when you need more space) are more efficiently stored than list (that pay a full word to store the tail of each cell), so you'd get roughly twice as much elements for the same memory use.

If you cannot hold all elements in memory (this is what your number look like), you should go for a more abstract representation. It's difficult to tell more without more information on what your elements are. But maybe an example of abstract representation would help you devise what you need.

Imagine that I want to record set of integers. I want to make unions, intersections of those sets, and also some more funky operations such as "get all elements that are multiple". I want to be able to do that for really large sets (zillions of distinct integers), and then I want to be able to pick one element, any one, in this set I have built. Instead of trying to store lists of integers, or set of integers, or array of booleans, what I can do is store the logical formulas corresponding to the definition of those sets: a set of integers `P` is characterized by a formula `F` such that `F(n) ⇔ n∈P`. I can therefore define a type of predications (conditions):

```
type predicate =
  | Segment of int * int   (* n ∈ [a;b] *)
  | Inter of predicate * predicate
  | Union of predicate * predicate
  | Multiple of int  (* n mod a = 0 *)
```

Storing these formulas requires little memory (proportional to the number of operations I want to apply in total). Building the intersection or the union takes constant time. Then I'll have some work to do to find an element satisfying the formula; basically I'll have to reason about what those formulas mean, get a normal form out of them (they are all of the form "the elements of a finite union of interval satisfying some modulo criterions"), and from there extract some element.

In the general case, when you get a "command" on your data set, such that "add the result of mapping over this subset", you can always, instead of actually evaluating this command, store this as data – the definition of your structure. The more precisely you can describe those commands (eg. you say "map", but storing an (elem -> elem) function will not allow you to reason easily on the result, maybe you can formulate that mapping operation as a concrete combination of operations), the more precisely you will be able to work on them at this abstract level, without actually computing the elements.

Comment: Ok, first, sorry for the delay, got real busy suddenly.  Anyway, not sure I understand your answer all that well, but I'll check it because it's the only one and this thread seems pretty dead.  Basically the base data structure is arithmetic expressions with times, in the form of binary trees, that need be multiplied out completely, i.e.: (x1 + x2 + x3) * (x3 + x4 + x5). For reasons I won't go into, the above is considered in its simplest form when the times is pushed as far down in the tree as possible.

Comment: @mbunit: So your big data structure is one of those arithmetic expressions, just very big? I don't understand what your notion of, say, "removal of specific pair of items" is in this case.

Comment: yes, the arithmetic expressions, when in a binary tree form, are the "big data structures".  Here is an example of "removal of a pair of specific items": (x + -x + y) --> y  i.e., cancellation of terms; thus if we represent x + -x + y as a list, then it would remove the head and the head of the tail...  As I said though, the problem is that the arithmetic expressions are huge, and a naive list representation isn't working very well.

Comment: My answer, in this context, then becomes: why do you need to compute a "simplest form" if it's so large? Can't you record which operations have been performed (without actually doing the corresponding simplifications), and rewrite whatever question you're gonna ask on this structure to work on the non-simplified form directly? It all comes down to: what do you need to do with those?